# How to select item name from jList in netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, jlist

i have been trying to retrive data from mysql in the `list` and that is working fine but the problem is i'm not able to select the `name` of the `list`.. 
i want to select `name` (not index or value) so that i can complete my where clause

Here is my Code :-

```
private void proceed(){

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs=null;

    String i = jList1.getSelectedValue();




    try    {

     Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");

     conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel","root","root");

      stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select * from hotelbookings where GuestName = '"+i+"'");

    rs = stmt.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()){

    String BN = rs.getString("BookNo");
    String GN = rs.getString("GuestName");
    String AD = rs.getString("Address");
    String NOD = rs.getString("No_of_Days");
    String PN = rs.getString("PhoneNo");
    String ID = rs.getString("ID_Proof");
    String CN = rs.getString("Country");
    String ARD = rs.getString("Arival_Date");
    String DRD = rs.getString("Departure_Date");

    NewJFrame1_1 second = new NewJFrame1_1(BN,GN,AD,NOD,PN,ID,CN,ARD,DRD);
    second.setVisible(true);

    }

} catch(Exception e){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}


}
```

[Here is the image of my list ..Show List retreives the data from mysql ..and proceed button is used to take the selected name for modification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUDbt.png)

Here is The code for Show List Button:-

```
private void fillList(){

        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;


         try    {
         Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");

         conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel","root","root");

          stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select GuestName from hotelbookings");

         stmt.executeQuery();

             ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
             int i =0;
             DefaultListModel info = new DefaultListModel();

             while (rs.next()){
                 String[] data = new String[100];
                 data[i] = rs.getString("GuestName");
                 jList1.setModel(info);
                 info.addElement(data[i]);
                 i = i + 1;
                 jList1 = new JList(info);
             }

}
      catch(Exception e){

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, e.getMessage());
}




    }
```

fillList class:-

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
     fillList();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
private void fillList(){

PreparedStatement stmt = null;
Connection conn = null;

try    {
    Class.forName("java.sql.DriverManager");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hotel","root","root");
    stmt = conn.prepareStatement("select GuestName from hotelbookings");
    stmt.executeQuery();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
    int i =0;
    DefaultListModel info = new DefaultListModel();

    while (rs.next()){
        String[] data = new String[100];
        data[i] = rs.getString("GuestName");
        info.addElement(data[i]);
        i = i + 1;
    }
    jList1 = new JList(info);
} catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (this, e.getMessage());
}

}
```

Comment: i have already created list by retriving data from mysql .. but i'm not able to select the name ... from the list ... thanks in advance ..any further help is appreciated ..

Comment: firstly you select the row(name) in jList1 in user interface of your application. Then press button to call the proceed() method

Comment: yahh ...i did exactly same .. but no help... i have attached an image ..see that

Comment: then how can i use variable i to execute that statement?

Comment: above given answer use to fill the Jlist1 from mysql

Comment: fillList is alredy working .. the part which is not working is to select the name like Shanaya ..and then proceed the Name Shanaya will replace variable i ...like that

Comment: @Shivii44 please try with above edited answer. replace your fill method

Comment: @Shivii44 isn't fill the data from mysql?

Comment: @Shivii44 return any exceptions?

Comment: no there are no exception its just when cliking on show list button ...nothing hapened

Comment: please share the source code of class which containing the fillList() method

Comment: See that ..in edited code.if that is the thing you want. by the way...there's no class..

Comment: where you put fillList() method

Comment: currently what is the value of i pass to sql query

Comment: jList1.getSelectedValue(); this is the current value of i.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the basic problem with the `fillList` as far as I can tell from your posted code is the while loop. You create a new `JList` for every loop. This will make invalid (or should I say *dirty*) the `jList1` reference you have in the `proceed` method. You should not create a new `JList` every time. Just keep the same list for every loop. Do not even change it outside the loop. Just keep it the same and update its model every time.

To update the model, you have at least the following two options:

1. Create a new model every time, update it (ie add all elements you want in it) and call `jList1.setModel(your_created_model)`.
2. Set the model of the `JList` to `DefaultListModel` once (on construction time for example), and then in each `fillList` method call:

   1. Get the model from the list itself (via [`getModel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getModel--)). You know it's a `DefaultListModel` so you can safely cast it to one.
   2. Remove all elements from the model (vis [`removeAllElements()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html#removeAllElements--)).
   3. Add all new elements from the `ResultSet` to the model.

Take for example the following code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;

public class Main {
    public static void fillList(final JList<String> list) {
        final DefaultListModel<String> model = (DefaultListModel<String>) list.getModel(); //Step 1: Get the model and cast it to DefaultListModel.
        model.removeAllElements(); //Step 2: Remove all elements from the model.
        final double rand = Math.random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            model.addElement("name " + Math.round((1 + i) * rand * 100)); //Step 3: Fill the model with new elements.
    }

    public static void proceed(final JList<String> list) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(list, "You selected: \"" + list.getSelectedValue() + "\"!");
        //Here you have the selected value approprietly to do whatever you like with...
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final JList<String> names = new JList<>(new DefaultListModel<>()); //Do not forget to set the ListModel of the list to DefaultListModel!

        //List initialization:
        names.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        fillList(names);

        //Creating the buttons:
        final JButton fill = new JButton("Fill"),
                      proceed = new JButton("Proceed");

        //Adding listeners:
        fill.addActionListener(e -> fillList(names));
        proceed.addActionListener(e -> proceed(names));

        //Creating buttons' panel:
        final JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.add(fill);
        buttons.add(proceed);

        //Scroll pane of list:
        final JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(names);
        scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));

        //Main panel:
        final JPanel contents = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        contents.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        contents.add(buttons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        //Frame:
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("List of MesureTypes.");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(contents);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It utilizes the second option (refilling the model each time).